# Replacement for "pegged" in "pegged for disposal"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, vocabulary, appropriate

I am having trouble finding an appropriate word for the following situation:

I have a group of objects which require certain actions to be performed on them. Before performing any action on any of the objects, I assess each one and determine which action will be performed.

The action at issue is "disposal", where I am looking to say that certain objects have been "**pegged for disposal**".

Specifically, the word "*pegged*" troubles me here as it seems almost conversational, whereas the affectation I am going for is more business-oriented.

- "Marked for disposal" is out of the question as no marking has been made, simply an act of judgement having passed.
- "Requiring disposal" also does not fit the bill as the objects themselves do not require disposal. It is not an assessment of their state but rather a judgement that has been passed upon them.
- "Selected for disposal" seems to assume that the main action we are here to perform is disposal when in fact it is but one of several possibilities.

I am looking to avoid changes of the noun to an adjective, i.e. "objects *deemed disposable*" as this changes the meaning of the phrase as with the earlier example of "requiring".

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is good to see that you use your language with care. But I don't think I agree with you about *marked*: it is common enough to use the term somewhat more loosely/metaphorically, not requiring an actual mark. The same applies to *selected*: the objects are selected for disposal. Whether or not disposal is their primary function or possibility doesn't seem relevant to me. Other alternatives are *chosen, designated, culled*, etc. Lastly, I see no problem with adjectives like simply *disposable* (without *deemed*), nor with infinitival phrases like *to be disposed.*

Comment: ... and the sense of 'mark[ed]' Cerberus mentions is clearly given in say AHD, Collins.

Comment: I would definitely use marked - pegged is just a less common synonym in this case.

Comment: @Stephen S: I'd probably use ***earmarked*** rather than plain ***marked***. I don't think the *formal/informal* distinction applies to either of those, but for more "colloquially metaphoric" contexts I'd say ***slated*** is more likely than ***pegged*** (which latter sounds at least *slightly* odd to me).

Comment: Yes, I agree with ***earmarked***, the usual metaphoric term in the UK. (It emanates from the practice of clipping the ears of cattle, in order to mark the ones set aside for some purpose - possibly slaughter).

Comment: You make the judgment, but what do you do?  Do you list it?  Do you put it in a database under "dispose"?  You don't tag it or mark it.  How do you remember what's what?

Comment: It's possible we don't understand what you mean by "pegged". Can you explain that? It's entirely possible that is not only conversational, but that it also doesn't have the meaning you are looking for.

Comment: @Xanne He either marks it in *some* sense or deals with everything personally or orally.

Comment: @Ily If it's all in his head, he doesn't need to worry about what he calls it, does he?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with _selected_. If I were to sort through my clothes I could make several piles: those _selected_ for retention; those _selected_ for offering to relatives; those _selected_ for donation to charity and those _selected_ for the rag bag. I understand your point but selection is not necessarily an binary operation.

Comment: Sorry, I see I did not fully give the context of the situation -_-" I keep trying to make the description generalized and it ends up vague in different ways each time. I ended up going with **slated** which, as opposed to @FumbleFingers 's description of it as "colloquially metaphoric", it fits more with the level of formality I was looking for.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Consider **slate:**

> **2. a.** To put down (a name, etc.) on a writing-slate; **to set down, book, *for* something;** also constructed *to* with infinitive.  Also, to plan, propose, or schedule (an event). Chiefly *U.S.*

(OED, bolding mine)  The phrase "slated for disposal" is not uncommon in American English:

[Thousands of beef cutlets slated for disposal sold in Japan](http://wwlp.com/2016/01/14/thousands-of-beef-cutlets-slated-for-disposal-sold-in-japan/)

[EPA Seeking Comment On Re-classifying PCB-Contaminated Building Materials Slated For Disposal](http://www.rtmcomm.com/index.asp?bid=109&rec=113&button=Search&cat=0)

Answer (score 38):

You have rejected **marked** because "no marking has been made, simply an act of judgement having passed". In this sense you are treating "marked" as the past participle of the verb "to mark".

However, I contend that **marked** is in fact the right choice. [The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marked) gives us the following definitions for marked as an *adjective*:

> *adj.*
>
> 1. Having one or more distinguishing marks.
> 2. Clearly defined and evident; noticeable: *a marked increase in temperature*.
> 3. Singled out, especially for a dire fate: *a marked man*.

Definition 3 is the relevant one here: *singled out*.

Comment: I actually don't think 3 is the right sense: it is highly idiomatic and more specific than in the OP's case. Senses 1 and 2 don't really fit either. I think the ordinary past participle *marked* is the best interpretation. I agree with you that *marked* would be fine in this case.

Comment: @Cerberus is mistaken. Three is the right sense and not idiomatic at all, although the example is rather misleading. Per OP, the projects designated for replacement have been definitionally singled out regardless of any physical markings. Furthermore, in almost any business setting, there *will* be markings *somewhere* (flowchart, work orders, notepads, &c.) so that it does include the physical marking sense as well.

Comment: I admit, I agree with your reasoning. After reassessing my position on the matter, I believe my problem with using **marked** is simply a subjective one of personal connotations. I'm relying on my sense of the language and the word **marked** just doesn't fit in context. I understand I was probably too vague in *giving* the context -_-" sorry about that. I selected another answer that, to my ears and acquired sense of the language, feels to be the appropriate word.

Comment: @GuyPassy - Thanks for the explanation. And I think you have made a very good choice with your selected answer.

Comment: @lly: Perhaps I was not clear enough: I think *marked* is fine in the OP's example; I just don't think that this use of marked is the one defined in sense 3 from the Free Dictionary. I rather feel that the sense in which it is used here is the ordinary past participle, not the adjective (as far as such a distinction makes sense).

Comment: objects marked for disposals means the objects actually have MARKS on them. They might have an x on them, or a tag stuck on them. But marked is a physical thing.

Comment: @Lambie - Sure, that may be the etymology of it. But I see nothing wrong with shouting "Hey John, get rid of the two on the end" and then considering them marked for disposal. The accepted answer is similar: to slate something originally meant to write it down on a slate, but it is used metaphorically these days.

Comment: I guess a potential issue is that "marked" might be misunderstood as being used literally, since it often is, whereas "slated" is more obviously metaphorical.

Comment: slated is a writerly term, a journalistic term; marked is a technical term for physical objects;  flagged is a term used in identify items in a list. These terms are all used in different contexts and for different purposes. None is less or more formal. They are all formal. And all three can mean: designated, which is generic and does not contain any specific semantic trait, and just mean identified as some thing. Designated for disposal.

Comment: @Lambie - I disagree that marked is only for physical objects. I can "mark" something in a list, by adding a checkmark, just as easily as I can "flag" my emails for follow up.

Comment: Yes, you can mark something on a list with an x.  But without more information here from the OP, I would not choose: marked for disposal. We should have asked for more context from the  outset. That said, context is everything. "Resistance is futile". I am just saying each term can have a specificity. And for now, we're being jerked around by a lack of it.

Answer (score 20):

Typically, in programming or in bureaucratic endeavors, lists of items are:

1) flagged for disposal [items in a list are flagged for disposal]

OR

2) tagged for disposal [in the real world, to be placed in the garbage bin]

And pegged is for describing people or situations and means: labeled. The politician was pegged as a revisionist.

Comment: I think all of those words would be fine, although they are admittedly somewhat informal, which is what the OP didn't want.

Comment: @Cerberus Sorry but you are mistaken. In a business context, flagged is used all the time and there is nothing informal about it. Of course, we have no idea what is being flagged.

Comment: I cannot agree with you there: in business, informal language is not at all uncommon. I had given your answer an up-vote, by the way.

Comment: @Cerberus For purposes of business communications, in which widgets, processes and procedures are being discussed in internal memos, etc., the word flagged is business oriented, just like the OP requested. For example, if you are discussing the agenda for a meeting, one person could write to another: I've flagged the important items for your attention. This would not be ""informal"" usage; it would be the only usage for this meaning of pointing out items as important.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=PGknvnEsLqgC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=business+English+%2B+flagged+items&source=bl&ots=G0OP11k0L7&sig=3l0GXnaTrmVgLecLzW3YRhm74ok&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisopzEs9TTAhUi0YMKHfNPA7IQ6AEIYDAJ#v=onepage&q=business%20English%20%2B%20flagged%20items&f=false

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot access that page. I would really consider *flagged* for items on an agenda to be less formal than 'average', unless actual flags (like symbols) were involved. "Marked" or similar would be neutral with respect to formality, at least for me.

Comment: Unless the program involves an actual "flagging" protocol like StackEx, **in any situation where "flagging" or "tagged" are appropriate marked is *more* appropriate**. Programming flags and tags are a case of technical jargon; it shows up in other contexts but is only an improvement to the extent they make things less formal, which OP was eschewing.

Comment: I gave this a +1, though "slated for disposal" is the usage I'd go with.

Comment: slated for disposal is fine. But in list of items, one would say flagged. Whereas you could say: old industrial machines slated for disposal. Flagged is not an "informal term. It is used for LISTS. A list of objects some of which are flagged for disposal [in a written document].

Answer (score 12):

Designate, as in "Designated for disposal."

Comment: But in any case where "designated for disposal" works, "marked for disposal" would work better. It's just the more awkward latiny cousin.

Comment: @lly Why do you say that marked would work better? I interpreted the question as looking for a formal verb which did not have an alternative (esp. more common) definition which was a physical action. "Mark," "Slate," "Flag," "Tag," "Label" all make sense, but can be used to describe specific physical actions as well. I would say words like "identify" or "designate" are the best words to fulfill the requirements of the question. Although, clearly, the author does not!

Comment: "Designate" literally means to place a physical sign upon something as well. It's nearly exactly identical to 'mark', just from a different original language. "Identify" doesn't really work since, at the literal level we're apparently working at, it means to discover a preëxisting status and not to mark something for an action separate from its own identity.

Comment: @lly Regarding "designate:" what is the original language? Would you mind pointing me to this definition? I am not seeing it in English dictionaries that I have checked.

Comment: [Latin](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50844).

Answer (score 10):

A possibility that seems to deliver the "when in fact it is but one of several possibilities" part of your question is

**[Identified](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/identify) for disposal**

> identify:
>
> To establish or recognize the identity of; ascertain as a certain person or thing
>
> To ascertain as having a certain characteristic or feature

Examples:

[Land identified for disposal](https://www.heller.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Pershing-county-lands-bill)

> In the Winnemucca District Office of the BLM’s resource management
>   plan, over 300,000 acres of BLM lands in Pershing County have been
>   identified for potential disposal. The sale or exchange of these lands
>   will create important economic development opportunities for Pershing
>   County. This bill would allow the sale land of up to 150,000 acres
>   identified for disposal.

[Assets](http://www.uow.edu.au/about/policy/UOW058659.html)

> Assets identified for disposal may be dispensed with using the
>   procedures below. Acceptable methods of disposal are:...

Answer (score 7):

Some form of 'marked' ('designated', 'slated', 'slotted') probably remains your best option since—aside from their figurative senses—you almost certainly *are* marking *something* to record which actions are being taken to which items. "Pegged" is a precise (and *less* appropriate) synonym to each of them, since you're not talking about literally placing a peg in a literal board.

Since it's only been mentioned in @Cerberus's comment so far, though, I'll note you're also wrong about

## [selected](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175031)

> ...chosen; picked out...

It remains perfectly appropriate. Regardless of what your *primary* action may be, the items selected for deletion have been selected for deletion, just as all the other items have been selected for whatever process they'll undergo.

Comment: I did end up going with, as you say, *some form of 'marked'* - specifically **slated**. I take your point regarded selected, though still I contend that it does not fit in the specific context. I understand that the context I gave is... lacking

Answer (score 5):

You might consider **earmarked**, the past participle of "[to earmark](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/earmark)":

> to set aside or mark out for a specific purpose

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

---

*This was a very good suggestion from FumbleFingers in comments on the question which deserved to be made into a proper answer*

Answer (score 1):

**Assess** may be the term you need.

You are identifying objects for disposal that, you say, may not be disposed of; that is only one option.  So perhaps you are assesing for disposition, where the disposition is yet to be determined, e.g., as an appraiser of a variety of items in an estate might do.  Some items will be sold at auction; some will be disposed of one way or another.

From Google:

> as·sess əˈses/ verb verb: assess; 3rd person present: assesses; past
>   tense: assessed; past participle: assessed; gerund or present
>   participle: assessing
>
> ```
> evaluate or estimate the nature, ability, or quality of.
> "the committee must assess the relative importance of the issues"
> synonyms: evaluate, judge, gauge, rate, estimate, appraise, consider, get the measure of, determine, analyze; informal size up
> ```

Comment: I think the *pegging* OP is trying to replace is the result of an assessment:  “I assess each one and determine which action will be performed.”

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Why doesn't he just use it then?

Comment: I think that the assessment will result in pegging or not pegging.  All items will be assessed. Only some of them will be designated for disposal.

Answer (score 0):

*"Marked for disposal" is out of the question as no marking has been made, simply an act of judgement having passed.*

You artificially and wrongly limit yourself to the marks being on the equipment being marked for disposal.  After all, the mark could have been made on an inventory report.

(If your reply is that there was no marking on an inventory report, how are you transmitting to others the requirement that the equipment must be disposed?  **There must be some marks somewhere**, even if those marks are what we call writing.)

I prefer "flagged", though, if you want something formal.